# GPG keys not shared between Windows and Visual Studio Code dev container... what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnupg, vscode-remote

As explained in [Sharing GPG Keys](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials#_sharing-gpg-keys) official documentation:

- I'm running Windows and I've installed [Gpg4win](https://www.gpg4win.org/)
- I've configured the key using the Windows GUI

**Keys is listed** correctly:

```
PS C:\Users\Me\Desktop> gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long
C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\pubring.kbx
------------------------------------------------
sec   rsa4096/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2023-07-05 [SC]
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
uid                 [ultimo] Foo Bar <foo.bar@example.com>
```

**Signing works**:

```
PS C:\Users\Me\Desktop> echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

test
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=VrEc
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

My **dev container** has `gpg` and `gnupg2` already installed.

```
root@741303da2f51:/var/www/html# apt list gpg   
Listing... Done
gpg/stable,now 2.2.40-1.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

root@741303da2f51:/var/www/html# apt list gnupg2
Listing... Done
gnupg2/stable,now 2.2.40-1.1 all [installed]
```

Inside the container however, nothing works. First run of `gpg --list-secret-key`:

```
root@e2af1977ecfc:/var/www/html# gpg --list-secret-key
gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
```

On subsequent run of `gpg --list-secret-key`, it returns nothing.

```
root@e2af1977ecfc:/var/www/html# echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No secret key
```

Comment: Can you check where is your GPG configuration file is located on dev container (usually, it's located at `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf` )?

If it is empty that's mean you are facing message 

`gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: No secret key`

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by Win4gpg (and GnuPG) [recently moving away from kbx](https://www.gpg4win.org/version4.2.html) keyring to more performant SQLite database **keyboxd** by default.

With Gpg4win >4.2 all you have to do to migrate back to kbx:

```
C:\> gpg-disable-keyboxd
```

This should be all you have to do for devcontainer to pickup the keyring (don't forget to rebuild container).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think you need to import the `GPG key` into the `GPG keyring` within the container! So, first of all start a shell inside your container, then export the GPG secret key from your host machine and copy the `secret.key` file to the container like this:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys --armor <key_id> > secret.key
docker cp secret.key <container_id>:/root/secret.key
```

Now import the GPG key into the GPG keyring within the container, then verify that the key has been imported successfully, like this:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
gpg --import /root/secret.key
gpg --list-secret-keys
```

This should work now without any "no secret key" errors. You can test it like below:

```
echo "TEST" | gpg --clearsign
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Supposedly, you don't have to import the secret key in the devcontainer (per the VS Code docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials#_sharing-gpg-keys). However, there are some reports that it doesn't work (reliably). Your method seems valid, however, I don't see the need for the first statement (`docker exec`). Perhaps it was meant to go in the second code block?

Comment: Don't do this, your embedding secrets in your container images. Your probably see the issue @xeevis mentioned. See workaround here for mac https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9217